# CSS: How to clear a floating object only one level, not the all the way to the left?

Tags: html, css

Im not sure if im describing this correctly.
I want an object among all floating objects to clear but not all the way to the left.

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/db0xacps/)

```css
#parent {
  background: greenyellow;
  width: 500px;
  height: 700px;
  padding: 15px;
}
#parent>div {
  float: left;
}
#object1 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
}
#object2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
#object3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">

  <div id="object1">


  </div>
  <div id="object2">

  </div>
  <div id="object3">
  </div>

</div>
```

As in, in the jsfiddle. I want the purple box to come below red box.
And no i dont want to reduce my parent's width.
And i dont want to contain red and purple inside a div.

Is there way for it.
Thanks?

Comment: You don't want to contain red and purple inside a div. Would an extra div around red, purple _and_ blue be OK?

Comment: There is a way—what you're trying to achieve is called a masonry layout, where elements will fill the next available space instead of clearing the entire row. However, there is no simple way of achieving this using CSS, but there are a handful of JS libraries out there that can do that, like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com).

Comment: Is adding some margin to the purple (an optionally red) box an option?

Comment: k i guess, only position and manipulation can lead to this or using scripts. there is no purely css way to achieve this as panther puts it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set lower width to parent,

```
#parent {width: 200px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/db0xacps/1/

Or wrap right elements, styles will be the same as you have.

```
<div id="parent">
     <div id="object1"></div>  
     <div>
         <div id="object2"></div>
         <div id="object3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/db0xacps/2/

Comment: hi, yea. but dont want to do that.

Comment: @Oceans12: there are no other way exclude these two how to do it. Float works as expected in you fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Use this styles in #object3 :

```
clear:left; margin:-200px 0px 0px 40px;

    #object3
    {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        background:purple;

        clear:left; margin:-200px 0px 0px 40px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some kind of `clear: left(x-level)` does not exist. If you don't want to change the width of the wrapper to force the element to move, you could change the outerWidth of the element itself by adding to the `margin-right`.

```
#object3
{
  margin-right: 300px;
}
```